# iptables traversal when connecting to docker client

Tags: linux, iptables, docker

How can the docker-host reach an exported port without hitting the iptables DNAT-rule?

Bonus: Why are the iptables log messages only shown with `curl 127.0.0.1:8082` but not with `curl localhost:8082`?

UPDATE: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629620, connecting to the container works with empty iptables rules too (`# systemctl stop iptables` clears all tables, sets policies to accept).

### Setup

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.2'

services:
    webapp:
        image: httpd:latest
        networks:
            - webapp
        ports:
            - "8082:80"


networks:
    webapp:
        driver: bridge
#port mapping does not work for internal networks
#        internal: true
```

### Observed Behaviour

1. Packet starts in OUTPUT chain
2. Packet leaves (lo), arrives again (lo)
3. Accepted by conntrack target in <sup>*filter</sup>**INPUT** chain

### Expected Behaviour

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8082
```

Although the nat-table [is traversed only once per connection][1], the counters for the DNAT should not be zero; Traversal for first packet:

1. Packet starts in OUTPUT chain
2. Packet leaves unchanged (-> lo), arrives again (lo)
3. Packet still unchanged: <sup>*nat</sup>PREROUTING -jump-> <sup>*nat</sup>DOCKER
4. DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:80
5. Routing decision --> <sup>*filter</sup>FORWARD (destination is foreign host)
6. <sup>*filter</sup>FORWARD -jump-> <sup>*filter</sup>DOCKER ang get accepted, further packets already accepted by conntrack target

### Counters

```
*nat (UPDATE: full output instead of DOCKER-chain)
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 44 packets, 4248 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 44 packets, 4248 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !br-cac172d73716  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.18.0.2           172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  br-cac172d73716 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !br-cac172d73716 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8082 to:172.18.0.2:80


*filter
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-cac172d73716 br-cac172d73716  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:80
```

with:
`docker network ls`

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
cac172d73716        docker_webapp       bridge              local
```

Comment: `iptables -t nat -L -n -v` please

Comment: the difference between localhost and 127.0.0.1 nowadays is that localhost also means ::1 (i.e. IPv6) and that is preferred.

Comment: updated the counters section;
according to localhost: shouldn't curl try 127.0.0.1 anyway as the container is only connected via ip4?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Due to compatibility reasons docker runs a TCP forwarding proxy by default, --userland-proxy=false switches port exposure entirely to iptables

---

Docker also starts a proxy-server by default. This service is a simple TCP forwarding proxy, accepting connections on the <sup>*filter</sup>INPUT-chain and forwards it into the container.

According to [this article](https://windsock.io/the-docker-proxy/), these are the main reasons for this proxy to exist:

- To <sup>*filter</sup>FORWARD rules, the device must be configured for routing, eg. `net.ipv4.ip_forward` must be set to 1. This is not enabled by default.
- Linux doesn't allow routing on the loopback interface (lo) by default, this can be enabled by setting `net.ipv4.route_localnet` to 1
- The people at docker wanted to support RHEL 6.5 which runs a 2.6 kernel. As discussed [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/4442#issuecomment-40126387), there exist cases where a packet has to be returned to the bridge it came from. This is only possible with [bridge hairpinning](https://lwn.net/Articles/347344/) which [was not available](https://github.com/docker/libcontainer/pull/366) on this system.

`ss -lnp | grep 8082` shows:

```
Netid  State   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port
tcp    LISTEN  0       128     *:8082              *:*                users:(("docker-proxy",pid=3066,fd=4))
```

---

If the kernel supports bridge hairpinning the switch `--userland-proxy=false` can be used.
The [docker manual](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/) states:

> The --userland-proxy parameter, true by default, provides a userland implementation for inter-container and outside-to-container communication. When disabled, Docker uses both an additional MASQUERADE iptable rule and the net.ipv4.route_localnet kernel parameter which allow the host machine to connect to a local container exposed port through the commonly used loopback address: this alternative is preferred for performance reasons.